# Download File link on ascx without popup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a link on an ASCX,  what I want to do is have a file download prompt without doing a popup.

example:

```
  <a href="download.aspx">Download</a>
```

then in the Download.aspx Page_Load I have:

```
    Dim dataAs String = "test"

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "test.dat")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", achData.Length.ToString())
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.Write(data)
    Response.End()
```

Is this the right way? My other way was putting the code in the post back of the ASCX

```
<asp:button text="download" id="theButton" />
```

.vb

```
Public Sub theButton_Click()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "test.dat")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", achData.Length.ToString())
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.Write(data)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: your question need more details. do you want to allow users to download a file or your desire text? 
The source is a file or just your data which actually is a string. please specify

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose is of the function theButton_Click

Comment: theButton_Click is what I had originaly to handle it in a post back.

Answer (score -1):

The content disposition can be either attachment or inline, e.g.:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline")
```

If you make it an attachment, the browser will typically display a popup asking the user whether they would like to open the file or save it.  The browser is in control of what happens after you return the HTTP response.  The default filename may the one you suggest, or the browser may decide to ignore your filename altogether and maybe use the ascx filename (Firefox listed this as a bug when I ran into it, IE seemed to consider it a "feature").

But if you make it inline, a "text/plain" content type will often get dumped into the browser screen without a popup.  Is that what you want?

Comment: What happens if I put this in an ASCX?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r Should be the same as for an aspx.  Note that `Response.End()` ends your HTTP response (best in the button click handler).  At that point it's entirely up to the user and the client browser what to do next.